# Get Primary Group From UserPrincipal C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, principalcontext

I want to locate the Primary Group from the code below

I can get all the Groups for a user, but which one is the primary group?

```
        string primaryGroupName = String.Empty;
        using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "userName"))
            {
                foreach (Principal p in user.GetGroups())
                {
                    WriteLog("PrimaryGroup Name(s)???:");
                    WriteLog(p.Name);
                    primaryGroupName = p.Name;
                }
            }
        }
```

Whats returned from the code above is...

> Domain Users
>   Administrators
>   Schema Admins
>   Enterprise Admins
>   Domain Admins
>   ..and a few more

What is the Primary Group?

Comment: You can get the primary group id, but I don't know how to get from there to the name of the group.      `var userEntry = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry; var primaryGroupId = userEntry.Properties["primaryGroupID"].Value;`

Comment: @Amy Thanks that seems to give me an id (i.e. 513) now how to I use the id to grab the group name?

Comment: I said I don't know how to do that, sorry.

Comment: Is it possible the last numbers of the SID is the "id"? Sid=S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-513

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea: The `primaryGroupID` holds the RID (Relative Identifier) of the group that is the primary group. The RID is the last set of numbers in the SID. The rest of the SID identifies the domain. So you can figure out the SID of the group using the SID of the user and the `primaryGroupID`.

I wrote a couple articles about this. One called [What makes a member a member?](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html), with a section describing the primary group. But also an article called [Finding all of a user’s groups](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/08/finding-all-of-a-users-groups.html) where I shared some code to find the primary group. I have found that using `DirectoryEntry` directly is *always* faster than using `UserPrincipal`/`GroupPrincipal`, so that's what my examples use:

Here is the method:

```
private static string GetUserPrimaryGroup(DirectoryEntry de) {
    de.RefreshCache(new[] {"primaryGroupID", "objectSid"});

    //Get the user's SID as a string
    var sid = new SecurityIdentifier((byte[])de.Properties["objectSid"].Value, 0).ToString();

    //Replace the RID portion of the user's SID with the primaryGroupId
    //so we're left with the group's SID
    sid = sid.Remove(sid.LastIndexOf("-", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
    sid = sid + de.Properties["primaryGroupId"].Value;

    //Find the group by its SID
    var group = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://<SID={sid}>");
    group.RefreshCache(new [] {"cn"});

    return group.Properties["cn"].Value as string;
}
```

To use that from your code, you would do this:

```
var primaryGroupName = GetUserPrimaryGroup((DirectoryEntry) user.GetUnderlyingObject());
```

That method just returns the name of the group, but you can modify it as you need.

All that said, `513` is always the RID of the built-in Domain Users group.